# All combinations of two table in Powerquery

Tags: merge, powerquery, m

This is a question about Power Query/ M.

I have two tables: one with unique objects and one table with two columns (year and €).
I want to merge the two tables to one table with rows for all the object and years.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Table2**  add column ... custom column ... using formula:

```
= Table1
```

Use arrows atop new column to [x] select and expand

That will give you every combination of **Table1** and **Table2**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table1),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"})
in #"Expanded Custom"
```